# WCF RIA And ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

So I am looking into solutions for developing a Silverlight web app, and right now ASP.NET MVC and WCF RIA have caught my eye.

Should these two be used in conjunction with one another? Or does the 'MC' in MVC play the role of the RIA services?

Would it be redundant to use both in the same web application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF RIA Services work great with Silverlight. So you just need to host your SL application somewhere, a static HTML page could work just great. You don't really need ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: As far as I understand things WCF RIA services are more like Dynamic Data projects that create a visual interface against a data store. WCF RIA creates a similar thing in terms of a callable API (not visual but programmatic interface)

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is a great platform for writing ASP.NET applications. However, it doesn't have a whole lot to offer when you're writing a Silverlight application. Instead, consider using RIA Services with the MVVM pattern. MVVMLight is a commonly used MVVM framework and John Papa has a few talks and samples out there on covering Silverlight, MVVM, and RIA.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net MVC is basically used for visualized applications. WCF RIA Services are API oriented and are *supposed* to be used with Silverlight. Or even **preferred**.

You could of course write an Asp.net MVC application that would return Json results for every request but what would be the point in doing that? In that case (if you would want to write all the code manually) you'd rather go with a standard WCF service instead.

WCF RIA Services are the fastest way to getting to your data in developer's perspective. Learn and use it. No better way basically.